# Unable to play higher resolution video on some iPads

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to play a video using MPMoviePlayerController. On some iPads, the video plays, on other iPads it does not.

Here is the code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self videoPath]];
self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
self.moviePlayerController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
self.moviePlayerController.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
self.moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[self.moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
... add to subview, play ...
```

MPMoviePlayerController lists the following compression restrictions:

> H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps.
>   (The Baseline profile does not support B frames.)
>
> MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile)

Originally, we were using H.264 at a higher resolution and the video worked with some our testers. Unfortunately, I was unable to get the video to play on my iPad (4th Generation). We kept the existing resolution and tried MPEG-4 Part 2 video but again, the video did not work. The only way we could get the video to work reliably was drastically reducing the resolution down to 480 x 640. The result looks horrible.

I added the notifications to monitor the load state and for the videos that failed to work, the modes would go from `MPMovieLoadStateUnknown` to `MPMovieLoadStatePlayable` back to `MPMovieLoadStateUnknown`. The videos that worked fine would go from `MPMovieLoadStateUnknown` to `MPMovieLoadStatePlayable` to `MPMovieLoadStatePlayable|MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK`.

I checked the errorLogs and accessLogs and they were both empty.

Any thoughts on what I might check next in order to get the higher resolution video to work on the iPads?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so Apple's MPMoviePlayerController documentation is a bit out of date. I referred to each iPad's technical specs and it revealed the source of the issue:

> Video formats supported: H.264 video up to 1080p, 30 frames per
>   second, High Profile level 4.1 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps,
>   48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats; MPEG-4 video
>   up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple
>   Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps per channel, 48kHz, stereo
>   audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats; Motion JPEG (M-JPEG) up to
>   35 Mbps, 1280 by 720 pixels, 30 frames per second, audio in ulaw, PCM
>   stereo audio in .avi file format

I was using videos at a higher resolution than 1080p using H.264 compression, and MPEG-4 higher than the supported resolution. Once we lowered the resolution everything worked perfectly.